# Replace String in c#

Tags: c#

I hava a specific string that I want to replace

```
string gerneralRootPath = docTab.Rows[0]["URL"].ToString();
string documentName = docTab.Rows[0]["NAME"].ToString();

var connectNamesAndURL = new StringBuilder(gerneralRootPath);
connectNamesAndURL.Remove(30,20);
connectNamesAndURL.Insert(30, documentName);
gerneralRootPath = connectNamesAndURL.ToString();
```

The output of gerneralRootPath  is 
**"Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/sales.2010+Implementation+Revised+Feb10.pdf"**

The output of is documentName is 
**"doc123"**

My gole is to remove everything after /PDF/.. so that final string looks like this 
**Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/doc123**

So how can I remove everything after the /PDF/..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string gerneralRootPath = "Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/sales.2010+Implementation+Revised+Feb10.pdf";
gerneralRootPath = gerneralRootPath.Remove(gerneralRootPath.IndexOf("PDF") + 3);
gerneralRootPath = gerneralRootPath +"/"+documentName ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `String.Split()` function:

```
string input = "Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/sales.2010+Implementation+Revised+Feb10.pdf";
string output = input.Split(new string[] { "/PDF/" }, StringSplitOptions.None).First() + "/PDF/doc123";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static string RemoveAfterPDF(string gerneralRootPath)
    {
        string pdf = "PDF";
        int index = gerneralRootPath.IndexOf(pdf);
        return gerneralRootPath.Substring(0, index + pdf.Length);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = RemoveAfterPDF("Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/sales.2010+Implementation+Revised+Feb10.pdf");
    }
}
```

Edit
This is better and much more reusable example:

```
class Program
{
    static string RemoveAfter(string gerneralRootPath, string removeAfter)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        int index = gerneralRootPath.IndexOf(removeAfter);

        if (index > 0)
            result = gerneralRootPath.Substring(0, index + removeAfter.Length);

        return result;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = RemoveAfterPDF("Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/sales.2010+Implementation+Revised+Feb10.pdf", "PDF");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;  

string result = gerneralRootPath.Replace(Path.GetFileName(gerneralRootPath), documentName);
```

With Path.GetFileName (from System.IO) you get your filename:

*sales.2010+Implementation+Revised+Feb10.pdf*

The result is:

> Documents/Z_Documentation/PDF/doc123

Answer (score 0):

please find the sample code

```
int i = gerneralRootPath.IndexOf("/PDF/");

 if (i >= 0) gerneralRootPath = gerneralRootPath.Substring(0,i+5);
```

i hope this will help you....